# NSIS Eclipse plugin not working in Helios and Linux platform

Tags: java, eclipse, nsis

I want to use the NSIS Eclipse plugin in Eclipse Helios and GNU/Linux platform. I have followed steps using [this link](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/index.shtml).

I followed these steps:

1. Go to Help-->Install new software.
2. Gave the update software link http://eclipsensis.sf.net/update.
3. I press the next button and I got the following errors :

   > Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
   >   net.sf.eclipsensis.feature.group [0.9.8.1] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Comment: Follow this link it might help you [link](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/How-to-Install-the-Nullsoft-Installer-NSIS-on-Linux-.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install it on Linux anymore, as the plugin itself explicitly demands a Windows platform in its dependencies and also explicitly states Windows operating systems as requirement on its homepage.

You might now argue that editing an NSIS script should still work fine, but to my experience, you have to compile and test NSIS scripts so many times, that without the NSIS compiler this really makes no pleasant experience. And the NSIS compiler is Windows only.

Comment: Thanks.I think same too.Is there any other tool is there for linux?

Answer (score 2):

Hm, see http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter2.html#2.4
"It it also possible to compile Windows installer on Linux, BSD or Mac OS X servers."

So NSIS compiler is *not* Windows only.

Comment: @yumins Thank you.but i have asked whether we'll create installer in linux or not using NSIS script?. your answer is not related.

Comment: @ILLA: sorry, my answer was meant to be a comment on Bananaweizen's answer.